# I have created pdf from html now I want to upload this pdf to cloudinary or our my server without saving it to client pc

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, cloudinary

I have created pdf from html now I want to upload this pdf to cloudinary or our my serverwithout saving it to client pc. I'm using Angular 4 on front-end

Comment: Have you checked the cloudinary documentation? what does it say about uploading via API?

Comment: They have example using file uploader. I don't want file uploader

Answer (score 0):

You can use Upload API to upload server-side. https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method